# react native error: "nothing was returned from render"

Tags: firebase, react-native

This is my sign out function which should redirect the user to the login screen after logout. But it is not working and I am getting the error "nothing was returned from this render".

```js
const signout= async() => {
    setShowLoading(true);
    try {
        const a= await auth().signOut().then(()=>{
            console.log(a);
            setUser(null)
            setShowLoading(true)
            if(!user)
            {
                return navigation.navigate('Login')
            }

           } 
        );

    }
     catch (e) {
        setShowLoading(false);
        Alert.alert(
            e.message
        );
    }
};
```

and this is my return in function

```
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
        <Button title="logout" onPress={()=>signout()}/>
        {showLoading &&
                <View style={styles.activity}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
                </View>
            }
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was returned from render function means, that one of you Components has nothing returned to it to render. In your codeblock's case, in a case where there is user, nothing is being returned. Either you edit renderMethod to return Home screen or you can navigate user to a different page before user is set or unset depending on your requirement. Either way, react must have something to render to the screen or it will throw an error like this.